# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes completely on random occasions

Tags: 20.04, crash

My Ubuntu 20.04 laptop freezes completely about 1-3 times a day. No response even from mouse or keyboard, the screen just remains static as it was when froze. Tried to reboot using the R.E.I.S.U.B method, doesn't work. Tried replacing the video card driver, doesn't work. I left the system monitor on screen and when it froze, everything seems OK, no RAM or CPU high usage.

The only thing that works is 5 sec power button.

Any more ideas please?